# How to pass extra arguments into JS Array.forEach()

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, iteration, parameter-passing

Just wanted to share a little trick I learned to pass variables into the scope of your JS Array.forEach() method.

I had a situation where I needed to use a forEach loop to build a dataset. But I needed to access variables in the current scope as well (I needed to be able to reference `this` in the loop).

This is the situation I was in:

```
var dataset = {
    data: [],
    backgroundColor:[],
};

items.forEach(function (item) {

    dataset.data.push(item.age);

    if (item.age < 2) {
        dataset.bgColor.push(this.green);
    } else if (item.age < 5) {
        dataset.bgColor.push(this.yellow);
    } else {
        dataset.bgColor.push(this.red);
    }

}, this);


this.refreshGraph(dataset);
```

Dataset isn't accessible from within the loop. So how do we access it while iterating?

I haven't seen this solution on stack overflow and it didn't fit any question I could find.

Answer below:

Comment: _"Dataset isn't accessible from within the loop."_, Not sure what you mean, `dataset` should be visible within the forEach callback as it is in a higher scope, higher scoped variables are visible to lower scoped code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a function out of scope of some data yet need to access it, you can use a curried function that takes that dataset as the first parameter and can still use `this` normally throughout:

```js
//curried function that uses `dataset` and `this` but it is not 
//in the context where the iteration happens 
function makeLoopCallback(dataset) {
  return function(item) {
    dataset.data.push(item.age);

    if (item.age < 2) {
        dataset.bgColor.push(this.green);
    } else if (item.age < 5) {
        dataset.bgColor.push(this.yellow);
    } else {
        dataset.bgColor.push(this.red);
    }
  }
}

//object to serve as `this` context for a function
var obj = {
  green: "Green",
  yellow: "Yellow",
  red: "Red",
  doSomething: function(items) {
    var data = {
        data: [],
        bgColor:[],
    };
  
    items.forEach(makeLoopCallback(data), this);
  
    return data;
  }
}

//set up some dummy data
var input = [ { age: 1 }, { age: 2 }, { age: 3 }, { age: 4 }, { age: 5 }, { age: 6 } ];

//call the function
console.log(obj.doSomething(input))
```

An alternative is to use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead of [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with a function that takes two parameters directly. Since `.reduce` cannot set the `this` context, you can just use [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to do it:

```js
//external function that uses `dataset` and `this` but it is not 
//in the context where the iteration happens
function external(dataset, item) {
    dataset.data.push(item.age);

    if (item.age < 2) {
      dataset.bgColor.push(this.green);
    } else if (item.age < 5) {
      dataset.bgColor.push(this.yellow);
    } else {
      dataset.bgColor.push(this.red);
    }

    return dataset;
}

//object to serve as `this` context for a function
var obj = {
  green: "Green",
  yellow: "Yellow",
  red: "Red",
  doSomething: function(items) {
    var data = {
        data: [],
        bgColor:[],
    };

    return items.reduce(external.bind(this), data);
  }
}

//set up some dummy data
var input = [ { age: 1 }, { age: 2 }, { age: 3 }, { age: 4 }, { age: 5 }, { age: 6 } ];

//call the function
console.log(obj.doSomething(input))
```

Comment: This is a great explanation. I learned about bind() and curried functions today. Very cool.

Answer (score 2):

With the abilities of es6
If you'll use an Arrow Function the **this** will be taken from

```
items.forEach(item => {
// You can use this as out of the forEach scope
});
```

[From MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the
>   enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal
>   variable lookup rules. So while searching for this which is not
>   present in current scope, an arrow function ends up finding the this
>   from its enclosing scope.

Another nice explanation:
https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4

Comment: Very nice I like this a lot better. Gonna steal it.

Comment: @NoahGary if it worked for you I'll be glad if you mark my answer ...

Comment: this made what I was doing in my code a little easier so thank you. I upvoted for that. But I really was trying to ask a different question altogether. Passing in a variable to a function that is out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

**I found a simple one**

if you don't need a context, you can simply use it to pass anything you want.

```
response.services.forEach(function(service) {

   //code

},undefined, <whatever i want to pass>);
```

just passed an undefined in second parameter and in third parameter i pass extra arguments into JS Array.forEach()

Short Example

> [1,2,3].forEach( myCallback, undefined, 'additionalFoo' );

[#ref](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/array-foreach-et-al-with-additional-parameters#content-4)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to pass a JSON object as the `this` argument.

so before we had:

```
Array.forEach(function(){}, this) 
// "this" is just an object ^^^^ just like anything else in JavaScript
```

Now we have:

```
Array.forEach(function(){}, {_self: this, dataset: dataset}) 

// you can access _self and dataset just as if they were in scope
```

And now you can make data changes while iterating with an anonymous function :)

Full example:

```
var dataset = {
    data: [],
    backgroundColor:[],
};

items.forEach(function (item) {

    dataset.data.push(item.age);

    if (item.age < 2) {
        dataset.bgColor.push(_self.green);
    } else if (item.age < 5) {
        dataset.bgColor.push(_self.yellow);
    } else {
        dataset.bgColor.push(_self.red);
    }
}, { _self: this , dataset: dataset});
```

Comment: You aren't using `this` anywhere in your code even though you pass it in. Yet you reference properties that will be attached to `this` without going through it. `dataset` will only work because it's matching the one from the outer scope - `var dataset`. However, `_self` doesn't reference `this._self`. I'm not sure what the point of it is, however - it seems easier to use arrow functions and/or curried functions if you want to be more generic.

Comment: This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and used in a lot of answers here on SO, also, you'll have to use `this._self` not just `_self`.

Comment: @VLAZ This is only a section of my full code and it is more just a proof of concept for others to understand. Please post your arrow function solution! I would love to see it.

Comment: @Titus I have looked through that documentation exhaustively. They show you can pass this in but they make no mention of how to pass extra variables the way I have here. Also you are incorrect. You can reference `_self` directly. I am doing it right now on our website.

Comment: Then you have a `_self` variable setup somewhere in a higher scope. The `thisarg` sets the execution context of the function (what `this` keyword will refer to) it does not introduce variables into the callback scope.

Comment: You probably didn't understand what it means, they say this: `thisArg: Value to use as this when executing callback` which means that you can use an object as an argument and that object will be referenced by `this` inside the callback function.

Comment: @PatrickEvans you're right. I didn't realize this sets the execution context. That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Titus thanks for helping me make that connection. I wasn't able to make that connection from the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I will be deleting this post. This helped to further cement my understanding of what is happening though. So not all a loss! haha

Comment: Were you trying to express how to introduce variable to a passed in function reference, and not an actual function expression: `items.forEach(someFunctionReference)` vs `items.forEach(function(){})`. As that would make more sense than to what you actually have. As your callback is in a lower scope and the dataset should be visible

Comment: So if my callback was another function outside of this method I may need to pass the argument in? or will `this` carry that variable with it?

Comment: If `someFunctionReference`was a function that was not defined in the same scope, or lower scope, where `dataset` was defined then you would need the `{dataset:dataset}` argument at the end and then access it with `this.dataset` inside the function.

Comment: Oh okay. That makes sense now. Okay, maybe I can resurrect this and still help some people out.

Answer (score 0):

> Array.prototype.forEach(callbackFun, ?this)

You can pass `dataset` as this argument to `forEach`

```
var dataset = {
data: [],
backgroundColor:[],
};

items.forEach(function (item) {

this.dataset.data.push(item.age);

if (item.age < 2) {
    this.dataset.bgColor.push(this.tempThis.green);
} else if (item.age < 5) {
    this.dataset.bgColor.push(this.tempThis.yellow);
} else {
    this.dataset.bgColor.push(this.tempThis.red);
}

}, {tempThis:this,dataset:dataset});


this.refreshGraph(dataset);
```

Comment: But now you don't have access to `this.green`, for example.

Comment: @VLAZ Now it's available.